# Entering data into an observable collection

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

My Problem is that when I call the the GetPrice() method in the azureService class it doesn't properly add the price to the observable collection in the original XAML.CS class.

I am positive that it is finding the price in the database as when testing I alerted the proper price.

Any help is welcome!

```
private void GetPrice()
{
     azureService = new AzureService3();

   azureService.FindPrice(productName);
}
```

Here (On the product page) is where I call the method GetPrice() to the azureService class.

```
  public async Task<string> findPrice(string pname)
        {
            //Method to initialise the database
            await Initialize2();
            //Method to Sync the database with the programme
            await SyncBookings2();
            Prices3.Clear();
            string productname;
            float price4;
            string answer = "false";

            productname = pname;

            try
            {
              List<Shop_Two> item = await shopz
             .Where(todoItem => todoItem.ProductName == productname)
             .ToListAsync();

                Prices3.Clear();
                foreach (var y in item)
                {
                    Prices3.Add(y.Price);
                }

                foreach (var x in Prices3)
                {
                    ProductPage.JOhn.Clear();
                    string g = "€" + x.ToString();
                    ProductPage.PriceList.Add(g);
                }
            }


            catch (Exception er)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Alert", "Error: " + er, "Ok");

            }
            return answer;
        }
```

Comment: You say "Here (On the product page) is where I call the method GetPrice()" but the code you've provided doesn't call GetPrice anywhere.

Comment: where are you calling GetPrice()?  Have you tried stepping through your code in the debugger?